# Java text-antialiasing: how to debug when not working?

Tags: java, antialiasing

I'm working on a fairly big Swing-based app (JPanels, JLabels, etc) and I have to find out why text-antialiasing (on JLabels etc) is not working.

As you may know, antialiasing normally works automagically (with Java 1.6 anyway), that is, when one creates a simple Swing-app (for example, just a JPanel with a JLabel on it) the text on the JLabel will be antialiased out of the box. No need for `System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","on")` and/or `System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true")`.

But this app is different, it does not antialias out of the box, it does not antialias with `System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","on")` and/or `System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true")` in the `main(String[] args)`, on also not with `-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on`  and/or `-Dswing.aatext=true` as VM-arguments. I've tried these and other all suggestions I could find on this site and on internet, but to no avail: this app just never antialiases, whatever I do or don't.

I'm out of options now. So my questions are:

- What steps can I take to find out why antialiasing is not working ?
- What properties should I check ?
- What code should I trace with the debugger ?
- What circumstances could cause antialias not to work ?

All insights are welcome.

Comment: Does the program use a custom look and feel? Have you tried changing the look and feel to see if it makes a difference?

Comment: After you called setProperty(), did you dump the equivalent getProperty() & check the value?  My understanding is that some properties can only be set at start-up.  I am not sure if that is one of them.

Comment: Does a dummy Hello-Swing-World application render nicely anti-aliased text on the target system?

Answer (score 1):

Try the advice in [System Properties for Java 2D™ Technology: awt.useSystemAAFontSettings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#aaFonts).

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.6, it looks like [`swing.aatext` is ignored](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6391267). However, as noted by @Andrew, [`awt.useSystemAAFontSettings` should work](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#aaFonts)...

One of the things you might want to do is dump out the `Map` for the `awt.font.desktophints` [desktop property](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/DesktopProperties.html) just to see what, if anything, has been set.